# How to Interpolate Over Data in Pytables Efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, pytables

I have very long arrays and tables of time-value pairs in pytables. I need to be able to perform linear interpolation and zero order hold interpolation on this data.

Currently, I'm turning the columns into numpy arrays using pytables' column-wise slice notation and then feeding the numpy arrays to scipy.interpolate.interp1d to create the interpolation functions.

Is there a better way to do this?

The reason I ask is that it is my understanding that turning the columns into numpy arrays basically copies them into memory. Which means that when I start running my code full throttle I'm going to be in trouble since I will be working with data sets large enough to drown my desktop. Please correct me if I'm mistaken on this point.

Also, due to the large amounts of data I'll be working with, I suspect that writing a function that iterates over the pytables arrays/tables in order to do the interpolation myself will be incredibly slow since I need to call the interpolation function many, many times (about as many times as there are records in the data I'm trying to interpolate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is difficult to answer because there is always a trade off between memory and computation time and you are essentially asking to not have to sacrifice either of them, which is impossible.  `scipy.interpolate.interp1d()` requires that the arrays be in memory and writing an out-of-core interpolator requires that you query the disk linearly with the number of times that you call it.

That said, there are a couple of things that you can do, none of which are perfect.

The first thing that you can try is down sampling the data. This will cut down the data that you need to have in memory by the factor that you down sample.  The disadvantage is that your interpolation is that much coarser.  Luckily this is pretty easy to do.  Just provide a step size to the columns that you access.  For down sampling factor of 4 you would do:

```
with tb.open_file('myfile.h5', 'r') as f:
    x = f.root.mytable.cols.x[::4]
    y = f.root.mytable.cols.y[::4]

f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
ynew = f(xnew)
```

You could make this step size adjustable based on the memory available if you wanted to as well.

Alternatively, if the data set that you are interpolating values for - xnew - exists only on a subset of the original domain, you can get away with reading in only portions of the original table that are in the new neighborhood.  Given a fudge factor of 10%, you would do something like the following:

```
query = "{0} <= x & x <= {1}".format(xnew.min()*0.9, xnew.max()*1.1)

with tb.open_file('myfile.h5', 'r') as f:
    data = f.root.mytable.read_where(query)

f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(data['x'], data['y'])
ynew = f(xnew)
```

Extending this idea, if we have the case where `xnew` sorted (monotonically increasing) but does extend over the entire original domain, then you can read in from the table on disk in a chunked fashion.  Say we want to have 10 chunks:

```
newlen = len(xnew)
chunks = 10
chunklen = newlen/ chunks
ynew = np.empty(newlen, dtype=float)
for i in range(chunks):
    xnew_chunk = xnew[i*chunklen:(i+1)*chunklen]
    query = "{0} <= x & x <= {1}".format(xnew_chunklen.min()*0.9, 
                                         xnew_chunklen.max()*1.1)

    with tb.open_file('myfile.h5', 'r') as f:
        data = f.root.mytable.read_where(query)

    f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(data['x'], data['y'])
    ynew[i*chunklen:(i+1)*chunklen] = f(xnew_chunk)
```

Striking the balance between memory and I/O speed is always a challenge.  There are probably things that you can do to speed these strategies up depending on how regular your data is.  Still, this should be enough to get you started.